# sharepoint 2013 video analytics and popularity

Tags: 2013, web-analytics, video

Have an Assets Library (template id 851) in SharePoint 2013.  It has some Videos in it (that is VideoSets).  When I view the Most Popular Items (Library ribbon), the resulting page has all zeros for every item in the list, however I have personally opened the video viewing page for each item many times so I know they've been viewed.

I've allowed enough time to pass for the following jobs to be run:
Analytics Timer Job for Search Service Application
Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Usage Data Import
Usage Analytics Timer Job for Search Application

Ive checked the Pages library on the site and it appears to be aggregating Most Popular items just fine.

Knowing a VideoSet is just a specialized DocumentSet, which is just a Folder, should I expect to see popular items for this library?  What else can I be trying to get the video views to show up?

Update: I placed a Content Search web part on a page and configured it to filter on the Video content type (ContentTypeId:0x0120D520A808) and configed the web part to render using the Diagnostic item template.  I mapped the ViewsLifetime and ViewsRecent in Property Mappings.  It renders blank values for all these.

Update: I am following along this and same results: [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj945725(v=office.15).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj945725%28v=office.15%29.aspx)